# Automate Solver with varying constraints range

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I want to create VBA to run Solver with these parameters:

Set objective: G6

Minimise

By changing Variables cells: J6:J----

Subject to the constraints: L6:L-- = N6:N--   (for example: L6=N6 , L7=N7 , ...)

The problem is that the variables and constraints ranges varies where I typed ---- and --. I know that the Variables cells range goes until a number on cell N1 and the constraints cells range goes until a number on cell N3.

I don't know how to create VBA but I tried that (it's not working):

```
  Sub SolverMacro()
Dim var
Dim var2
    var = Range("Sheet2!$N$1").Value
    var2 = Range("Sheet2!$N$3").Value
    SolverReset
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("L6", "L" & var2), Relation:=2, FormulaText:=Range("N1", "N" & var2)
    SolverOptions Assumenonneg:=True
    SolverOk SetCell:="$G$6", _
             MaxMinVal:=2, _
             ByChange:=Range("J6", "J" & var)
    SolverSolve userFinish:=True
End Sub
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro, where you set the solver by hand and then see if you can replicate that?

Comment: Hello, Marco. I tried that but the problem is the final range of the variables and constraints. How can I write, por example, L6:L20, but the number 20 is a reference to a cell of my sheet? Por example, L6:L & var  , where var = Sheet1!N3.

Comment: Can you maybe write down a few example of you constraints? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Can you replace `Range("L6", "L" & var2)` with `Range("L6:" & "L" & var2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone! I found an answer and it's working now. The code that works is:

```
Sub SolverMacroX()
        SolverReset
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim Aux As Long
        Aux = Range("$L$3")
        For x = 6 To Aux
            SolverAdd CellRef:="L" & x, Relation:=2, FormulaText:=Range("N" & x)
        Next
            SolverOptions AssumeNonNeg:=True
            SolverOk SetCell:="$G$6", _
                     MaxMinVal:=2, _
                     ByChange:=Range("J6", "J" & Range("$J$3")), _
            SolverSolve userFinish:=True
        End Sub
```